# how to get the values of multiple select menu with same name inside an echo function

Tags: php, html

The Fetch from databse works correctly

```
if( mysqli_num_rows( $selectRes )==0 )
{
    echo '<tr><td colspan="4">No Rows Returned</td></tr>';
}
 else
{
```

All the `ResultSet` is Stored into the `$row` correctly
On starting the While loop it creates Dropdown menus based on Number of 
rows fetched from the database,but when trying to acces the value of `(select  name = "subknow"` it is overwritten with the values of last select menu value 
of the last corresponding row fetched from databse)

```
    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $selectRes ) )
   {
      echo "<tr><td>{$row['Sno']}</td><td>{$row['Section']}</td><td>{$row['Name']}</td><td>{$row['Subject']}</td>
            <td><select  name='subknow'><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option></select></td>
            <td><select  name='notes'><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option></select></td>
            \n";
            if(isset($_POST['submitbutton'])){

               $fed1 = $_POST["subknow"];
               $fed2 = $_POST["notes"];
               $tot= $fed1+$fed2;
               echo "$tot";
```

As mentioned Before it only adds the values ok $fed1 and $fed2 of the last 
row fetched.

```
               $query="insert into resultsg values('$sub','$fed1','$fed2')";
               mysqli_query( $con,$query );
          }
```

Please help me!!..I think we should use arrays but cannot get to make it 
    work. Would appreciate Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using any html element whose occurrence are more than one, than give the name as an array like `notes[]` so that it can hold multiple selected value into it. Make following changes in your code:

```
<select  name='notes'>
```

change it to:

```
<select  name='notes[]'>
```

and fetch its value like:

```
$notes = $_POST["notes"];
```

here `$notes` is an array, use `foreach()` to get its individual values or some php array functions.

Comment: When i Use foreach($notes as $value) i will get the result of only the second select menu as individual array, but i need an array corresponding to the row fetched with all select values.

Comment: found the Answer myself but the suggestion helped so much thanks! :)

Comment: A little busy, that's great!!